# Finding the least 100-digit number, which has no $0$ in its decimal representation, that is divisible by the sum of its digits.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

An interesting question on number theory:

> Find the least 100-digit number, which has no $0$ in its decimal representation, that is divisible by the sum of its digits.

**My attempt**: let the number be
$$a_1 a_2 a_3.....a_{100}$$
Which can also be written as

$$10^{99}a_1 + 10^{98}a_2+\cdots +10a_{99}+a_{100}=(10^{99}-1)a_1 + (10^{98}-1)a_2+\cdots +(10-1)a_{99}+(a_1 +a_2 + ...a_{99} + a_{100})$$

The last term is divisible by the digit sum. But I don't know how to proceed further.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suggest solving it for shorter lengths, see if you can see a useful pattern.

Comment: I don't see any pattern , :-( @lulu

Comment: If nothing else, brute force should work for this. It seems plausible that the number is less than, say, $111\ldots12000000$ — that is to say, 93 ones followed by some other string of digits — so just doing a computer search starting from $(10^{100}-1)/9$ and taking the top 93 or so digits as given ones should find results pretty quickly.

Comment: Computer search shows that the smallest number is $111\dots 1122$, which is divisible by $102$.

Comment: I'd say that the "pattern" is that there is always an example very near the start of the search.  In your case, trial and error works very rapidly.

Comment: For pattern as $2$ and $5$ are then only primes who don't have a multiple of the form $1111....1$ because $2$ and $5$ divide $10$.  Think that this question is for $100$ digits rather than so $99$ or $101$  but of with have $1111...1$ divisible by the sum of the digits is specifically *because* $100$ digits is a number with only $2,5$ as prime factor.  I'd try this with lengths of $2,4,5,8,10$ etc and see if I can find a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better answer than "by computer" but still requires trial and error: this uses Fermat's Little Theorem.

Obviously ..$11$, ..$13$, ..$15$, ..$17$, ..$19$ are not divisible by their digit sums, which are all even.

..$16$ is not divisible by its digit sum $105$.

Since ..$11$ is divisible by $101$, neither ..$12$ nor ..$21$ are divisible by their digit sum $101$.

The harder part is to check ..$14 \pmod {103}$, ..$18 \pmod {107}$ and $..22 \pmod {102}$.

Note that ..$14 = $..$11 + 3 = (10^{100}-1)/9 + 3 = (10^{100}+26)/9$. Since $103$ is prime, finding $10^{100} \pmod {103}$ would help find ..$14 \pmod {103}$.

Now by FLT, $10^{102} \equiv 1 \pmod {103}$. Also by using Euclidean Algorithm or otherwise, we have:

$103 \times 3 = 309 = 10\times 31-1$, so $10^{-1} \equiv 31 \pmod{103}$.

Finally ..$14\times 9 = 10^{100}+26 \equiv 10^{-2} + 26\equiv 31^2 + 26\equiv 60\pmod {103}$, so ..$14$ is not divisible by $103$.

I leave ..$18 \pmod {107}$ to you.

For $..22 \pmod {102}$, since $102 = 2 \times 3 \times 17$ and divisibility by $2$ and $3$ are very easy to check, we just need to find $(10^{100}-1)/9 + 11 \pmod {17}$, and showing $10^{100}+98\equiv 10^4 + 98$ is divisible by $17$ is trivial.

Comment: By ..$11$ (for example) do you mean $11...11$?

Comment: More specifically, ..$xx := \underbrace{11\dots1}_{98 \ 1\text{'s}}xx$, which is clear from context.

Answer (score 0):

Trying it for shorter lengths of string with $2^k5^m$ digits.

The shortest $2$ digit number divisible by the sum of its digits is $12$ which is divisible by $3$.  It's clear $11$ is not divisible by $2$ but by adding $1$ we have a number whose sum is $3$ and thus divisible by $3$.

Whats the shortest $4$ digit number divisible by the sum of its digits. $1111$ is not divisible by $4$ but by adding $2$ more we get a number divisible by $6$.  Adding $2$ to the end won't do us any good as $1113$ is odd and not divisible by $6$ but add $11$ to the end will.  $1122$ is divisible by $6$.  That's *probably* the lowest. $1121$ and $1112$ are not divisible by $5$.  $1120$ ends in $0$. And $111b$ is divisble by $3+b$ if $111b-(3+b)=1107=$ is divisible by $3+b$. Hmm $1107=27\times 41$ and so if $b = 6$ then $1116$ is divisible by $9$.  And that's the lowest.

Okay... I'm sort of seeing a pattern here.

$111111......1b$ with $99$ ones will have  sum of digits of $99+b$.  If $b=3$ or $9$ we will have $111...1b$ divisible by $3$.  But $99+b$ well be even while $b$ is odd.

Otherwise to have $99+b$ divide $11111....b$ we must have $99+b=101,103,107$ And I this we can verify that $11111...b= \frac 19(10^{100}-1) + (b-1)\not \equiv 0 \pmod {101,103,107}$.  Maybe....

But $11111.....22$ will have a sum of $102$.  So it is divisible by $3$. And by $2$.  Just need to show it is divisible by $17$.

Okay so what is $\frac 19 (10^{100}-1)+11 \pmod{17}$?

$9^{-1}\equiv 2 \pmod {17}$ as $2\cdot 9 \equiv 1 \pmod 17$.  And $10^{16}\equiv 1\pmod {17}$ by FLT.  So $10^{100}\equiv 10^{4}\pmod 17$.  $10^4\equiv ((-7)^2)^2\equiv 49^2 \equiv (-2)^2 \equiv 4\pmod{17}$.

So $1111....1 \equiv 2(4-1)+11\equiv 17\equiv 0 \pmod {17}$

....

Not satisfying....